# how to only get data once from firebase or to check if the new data coming is updated

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this use case where I need to listen to firebase only once and not any updated data .How do we achieve this in firebase in react applications ?
How can we know this from the doc before we extract data out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

On Real-time Database use `.once(...)` on a `Reference`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

On Firestore use `.get()` on a `DocumentReference`
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#get

It doesn't have much to do with React.